# Apache Phoenix SqlLine configuration

Tags: apache-phoenix

I'm using Sqlline and need to increase the size of the query thread pool.

I added a "sqlline.properties" file to ~/.sqlline and added the line
`phoenix.query.threadPoolSize=256`

But the thread pool size is still 128.  So, what file do I need to edit and what's the syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

follow these it might get resolved

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/224984/phoenix-query-call-from-java-on-larger-data-set-fa.html

https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150633/phoenix-query-on-large-table-fails-because-of-quer.html